# Is this abuse? Lost 16 rep all at once across 9 unrelated questions

Tags: support, status-completed, voting

This may be the wrong area for this, but it seems like something that would be banned by the TOS.  Apparently I upset somebody and a lot of my answers were downvoted all at once.  Kinda sucks losing my internet points like this!

[image: Lost SE rep]

edit: realized that one of the rep losses was my own.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not sure about an explicit ban in the TOS, but the system automatically catches unusual voting patterns and will roll back the changes if it fits its vote fraud heuristic. This rollback generally occurs once a day, so check back in a few hours to see if the votes are still there.

There's [a FAQ entry on Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19920/how-does-the-so-voter-fraud-detection-mechanism-work) that goes through the vote fraud detector in greater detail, and we'll look into it, but to preserve the integrity of the automatic fraud detection systems and prevent gaming the system, we really can't talk about anything more specific.

Comment: Fixed itself overnight just like you predicted.  Was there any way to tell who did that?

Comment: @insta We can't really get into the details so as to preserve the special sauce of SE's vote fraud system, so... no comment. :) Glad it was reversed, though.